# Developing a non-GUI user agent in Objective-C using NSDistributedNotificationCenter

Tags: objective-c, xcode, multithreading, daemon, nsnotifications

I would like to create a user agent in Objective-C that listens for notifications from the default `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`. The agent will not have a GUI. When I create a Cocoa application (I will also be using Distributed Objects, which I think is only in Cocoa) in Xcode, however, Xcode sets the project as a GUI application.

In the main function, I remove the `NSApplicationMain(...)` function call to remove the GUI elements from the application. However, now I can't get the thread to wait (listen for) notifications coming in from the `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`. The app just starts and quits immediately.

I looked into using the `NSRunLoop` from the current `NSThread`, however, it seems that `NSRunLoop`s only wait on `NSPort`s. There's no mention of waiting on `NSNotifications`.

Comment: If you mean `NSProxy` and `NSDistantObject` and that whole mess, it's in Foundation, not AppKit (both of which are Cocoa). You don't need AppKit for distributed objects. However, you might want to look at XPC. It's new in Lion, but depending on what you're doing, it may be a lot easier than using distant objects.

Comment: @JasonCoco Thanks for the info. I took a look at XPC. It seems that XPC is a way to break up your application into separate "processes" such that if one process crashes it doesn't effect the other process. For example, if I was writing a Mail.app-type application, I may want to write the mail fetcher in one process and the mail reader in another. If the mail fetcher crashes, I can still read my downloaded mail. That was my impression of the use of XPC. In my case, I am writing a client-server architecture, and I'll need network access (not just IPC).

Comment: Okay. In that case you can just write a Foundation program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSDistributedNotificationCenter` is Foundation, so you don't need to create a GUI app. You can create a command line template, for example, and run it from terminal. As a very simple example, you could create an example that just prints out every distributed notification it receives below.

To build, copy into an Xcode template for a Foundation command line app, or simply copy into a text file named something like **test_note.m** and build according to the comments. In this example, the application will never end (`CFRunLoopRun()` never returns) and you will have to kill it by hitting CTRL+C from the terminal or killing it with something like `kill` or the activity monitor.

```
// test_build.m
// to build: clang -o test_build test_build.m -framework foundation

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Observer : NSObject

- (void)observeNotification:(NSNotification*)note;

@end

@implementation Observer

- (void)observeNotification:(NSNotification*)note
{
  NSLog(@"Got Notification: %@", note);
}

@end

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool {
    Observer* myObserver = [[Observer alloc] init];
    [[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:myObserver selector:@selector(observeNotification:) name:nil object:nil];
    CFRunLoopRun();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see. So, by "Cocoa" app, Xcode is really asking if you want to build a GUI app. I could very well write a CLI app and just #import the Cocoa libraries if need be. Correct?

Comment: Yeah, in the Xcode template chooser, the "Cocoa" app template is for an AppKit app. You can write a command line tool that uses AppKit, but there are a lot of caveats, you need to make sure you get a connection to the window server for some things to work right, other things just won't, etc. Basically, from the "Command Line" tool template, you get all of Foundation and CoreFoundation. You can add other Cocoa frameworks like CoreData, etc. If you want to use something from AppKit, you need to look at the docs more carefully.

Comment: That sounds good. By the way, with the above solution, would that be directly useable if I launch the application using launchctl (launchd) as a user agent? I've read through that documentation and it seems that they recommend that applications work "on-demand." However, it seems that in the launchd config file, I can only specify a port to listen to, in which launchd will start my application. However, I am unsure how to get that working with NSDistributedNotificationCenter. Perhaps it would be best to keep my user agent "alive?"

Comment: Also, is @autoreleasepool needed if I am using ARC?

Comment: Yeah, launchd favors on-demand style daemons, but it takes a lot more work. In your case, you might configure the launchd plist for this process to have launchd start the process when the user session starts and just keep it alive (i.e., re-spawn the process if it dies or crashes). This would mean that the user would have to manage starting and stopping the app using calls to `launchctl load` and `launchctl unload` respectively, but it would make development much easier.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian yes, the `@autoreleasepool` is needed because some libraries/frameworks may or may not be using arc. Either way, the new `@autoreleasepool` version is very quick and nice and certainly doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: Yup, I think I'll do just that. I'll keep the console app in a loop and just set the plist entry to "KeepAlive." Besides, I don't think I can write an on-demand style daemon using the NSDistributedNotificationCenter since there's no way to tell launchd in the plist what I am listening for and when to wake me up.